# VueJS: Chrome devtools doesn't instantly update an array (in parent component). Why?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

In the following code, I'm trying to get selected users from a list of given users (users array) via checkbox input (defined in a child component) in an array `selectedUsers` (defined in parent).

The problem is when I check/select the user, devtools doesn't update on first reaction. I've to navigate away from the selected component in devtools and then comeback to see the updated array.

#### app.vue (parent)

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div v-for="(user,idx) in users" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <child :user="user" :userIdx="idx" :selectedUsers="selectedUsers" /> <span>{{user.name }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import child from './child.vue'

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return{
                users: [
                 {id: 1, name: 'Allen'},
                 {id: 2, name: 'Jack'},
                 {id: 3, name: 'Obama'},
                 {id: 4, name: 'Donald'},
                 {id: 5, name: 'Winston'},

                selectedUsers: []
            }
        },
        components: {
            child
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### child.vue (child)

```html
<template>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="user.name" @change="onSelectedUser">
    </span>
</template> 

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user', 'userIdx', 'selectedUsers'],
        data(){
        },
        methods: {
            onSelectedUser() {
                var idx = this.userIdx

                if(event.target.checked) {
                    this.selectedUsers[idx] = event.target.value
                } 

                if(event.target.checked == false) {
                    this.selectedUsers.splice(idx, 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot showing array not updated (in devtools) on checkbox checked state(vuejs)]
[image: Screenshot showing updated array view in devtools]

Thanks

Comment: You probably should have a read of this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html - also, check out $emit. It's better if your child $emits an event that your parent binds to.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code, `this.selectedUsers[idx] = event.target.value`, I'm directly setting the value of an Array which vue is not able to pickup these direct modification to the array.

**Excerpt from the below linked page**

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes.

More info [VueJS common gotchas - why DOM isn't updating](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)